# Dynamic array using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically access arrays, otherwise I would have to duplicate my code, when in reality the only difference would be buildablesets1 and buildablesets2.

```
var buildablesets1 = [""];
var buildablesets2 = [""];
var buildablesetsx = "buildablesets" + playerturn;

for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
  if (doesOwnSet('player'+playerturn, set[i])) {
    if(playerturn===1) buildablesets1.push(set[i]);
  }
}

if (buildablesetsx.length > 1){
  var b = $("#buildsets"+playerturn);   
  for (k = 1; k < buildablesetsx.length; k++){
    b.append("<option value='" + buildablesetsx[k]+ "'>" + buildablesetsx[k] + "</option>");
  }
}
```

The code pushes any sets owned by the player to buildablesetsX. Then the dropdown box #buildsetsX is populated with all the owned sets.
1. How do I get the effect of buildablesetsX where X depends on the players turn.
2. I want to depopulate the dropdown box on each turn otherwise it will duplicate, since it is appending. (would apreciate a better way of doing this, ideally I want to populate the dropdown box only if there is a new set).

Plus sorry I understand that this question has been asked before, but I didnt understand the answers or the question exactly.

Comment: Instead of two variables, why not use an array: `buildablesets = [[""], [""]]`?

Comment: `window[buildablesetsx]` or use better coding as suggested by Barmar

Comment: @Barmar becausse buildablesets is unique for each player... I am not sure how that would work? Maybe you can post what you have in mind.

Comment: Extra info. This is for a Monopoly board game. There are 8 buildable sets in total. The idea is to populate a dropdown box with the sets a player can build upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you find yourself creating variables with sequential numbers, and wanting to access them dynamically, what you really should be using is an array. In this case, you should use a two-dimensional array:

```
var buildablesets = [[""], [""]];
```

The first dimension is the player number, the second dimension is the list of sets that player has built.

To access a particular player's sets, do:

```
buildablesetsx = buildablesets[playerturn];
```

The rest of your code will work as you've written it, with the above variable assignment.

Comment: What goes in buildable sets is for example, "Navy", "Red", "Orange", etc 8 in total. But who owns those sets can vary.

Comment: I updated the answer, I hope it will make it clearer. Anything you can do with a variable you can also do with an array element.

Comment: Maybe you didn't see that `buildablesets` is a two-dimensional array. Each element is a sub-array that's associated with a particular player.

Comment: Ok but how would I access it to populate the dropdown box? buildablesets[playerturn].length like so? How should this line be:  `code` b.append("<option value='" + buildablesetsx[k]+ "'>" + buildablesetsx[k] + "</option>"); `code`

Comment: I am getting a "Cannot call method 'push' of undefined " hmmm?

Comment: Fixed* playerturn is 2, it is undefined, i added an extra [""]

Comment: Like I said in the answer: players should be 0 and 1, not 1 and 2. Real programmers count from 0.